# in golang,how can keep console window open when the program is done which startup the exe by double click

Tags: windows, go

in windows when startup by double click the .exe
and when the programe is done by os.Exit(...)
so,is there anyway to  keep the console window open,just like auto run an cmd command.
I dontn want some solution with some PAUSE or some others thing to let it wait close.I  need completed exit the program,and keep the console window .

BTW,I think some way of open another console window,but fail with this code

```html
c :=exec.Command("start")

 if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
 }
 os.Exit(0)
```

Comment: You can launch a console window first (cmd) then run your .exe inside it.

Answer (score 6):

You could call `fmt.Scanf()`. I know it's hack and you wouldn't want to do it in a production application, but it works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
    fmt.Scanf("h")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need the program to exit completely, but keep the window open, run the program from a console.

1. `win+r`
2. type `cmd`
3. enter
4. navigate to the folder you have the binary in, by using `cd myFolder` to move into a folder, and `cd ..` to move one folder up
5. run the binary by typing `./myBinary.exe` and pressing enter
6. binary finishes running, and console stays open.

**EDIT:**
To be able to double-click, using pause in a batch-file is the simplest solution:

launch.bat

```
./myBinary.exe
pause
```

save in same folder as binary, and double-click to run.

You could write a program in a language of your choice that does the same thing as that batch file, if you really want to.

Comment: why? It might be easier to solve the problem than to fix your attempt at solving the problem @go-php-2016

Comment: that the needs of the projects.and I know your the normal way to startup the program.

Comment: and ,we can discuss ,if there is some way to auto build this bat file  or some ?

Answer (score 0):

> BTW,I think some way of open another console window,but fail with this
>   code

If you run *your_executable.exe* using the *cmd.exe* processor using the */k* option it should run the executable and also keep the console open.

```
cmd.exe /k your_executable.exe
```